# Performing clustering without a distance matrix

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning

I have `n` vectors and a matrix of similarity scores between them (e.g. vector 1 score of similarity with vector 4 is 1.3, and with vector 7 is 2.3). This matrix is partial (I don't know what is the similarity between many pairs of vectors) and the similarity is not a distance metric (e.g the triangle inequality doesn't hold). Is there still an efficient way to cluster the vectors such that similar vectors would end up in the same clusters?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you convert the similarity measure into a distance like d(x, y) = 1 - sim(x, y).